# how to read a particular attribute value in a node of xml using asp.net and send to textbox

Tags: asp.net, xml, listviewitem

I have this XML document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

    <NameDecoder>
      <Data>
        <Family ValueFrom="Family">
          <Item ItemMatchString="BLR" ItemValue="Bangalore"/>
          <Item ItemMatchString="HYD" ItemValue="Hyderabad"/>
          <Item ItemMatchString="GTR" ItemValue="Gunteur"/>
          <Item ItemMatchString="VZ" ItemValue="vIZAG"/>
          <Item ItemMatchString="KDP" ItemValue="Kadapa"/>
        </Family>
    </Data>
    </NameDecoder>
```

I have a text box in the design form where i enter suppose BLR it should give me an output of Bangalore in another text box.
I m new to this .please help me.I would like to store the attribute values in a dictionary and retrieve accordingly